# How to use the XQuery fn:idref() function?

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon, idref

I can't get the XQuery function `fn:idref()` to return anything.

I have this XML document **doc.xml**;

```
<doc>
  <foo idref="xyz"/>
  <bar xml:id="xyz"/>
</doc>
```

And this XQuery;

```
let $d := doc("doc.xml")
return $d/idref("xyz")
```

But the result is always empty. I'm guessing that the attribute `idref="xyz"` needs to be declared as type `idref` but can that be done without a schema?

I'm using Saxon XQuery 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the idref() function only retrieves attributes labelled as being IDREFs, and that only happens as a result of schema validation.

There's a deprecated legacy setting config.setRetainDTDAttributeTypes() that allows it to work as a result of DTD validation, but I wouldn't use it.

You can always do `doc("doc.xml")//*[@idref="xyz"]`. This will result in a serial search in Saxon-HE and Saxon-PE, but will make use of an index in Saxon-EE. I would generally recommend this over using the `idref()` function.

In XSLT, of course, you can use keys.

Comment: Great, thanks. I also have a similar issue but with an idrefs attribute. I'll ask a new question.