# Trying to simulate the XQuery function fn:idref() but without a schema

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon, idref

I want to search an XML document for the element that has an `idrefs` attribute containing a specific `id`. For example, given this XML document `doc.xml`;

```
<doc>
   <x1 idrefs="foo bar">
      <x2 idrefs="world hello"/>
   </x1>
   <x3 idrefs="ipsum lepsum"/>
   <a xml:id="bar"/>
   <b xml:id="hello"/>
</doc>
```

I want this XQuery;

```
let $d := doc("doc.xml")
return $d/local:getref("hello")
```

to return this element;

```
<x2 idrefs="world hello"/>
```

I believe that `fn:idref()` does exactly this, but only if `doc.xml` has an appropriate schema. Can this be done without a schema?

I'm using the Saxon XQuery processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to

[How to use the XQuery fn:idref() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433065/how-to-use-the-xquery-fnidref-function/6436368#6436368)

Without a schema, you need

```
//*[tokenize(@idrefs, ' ') = "hello"]
```